# Are Games for Windows Live games registered to a Gamertag, or a Windows Live ID?

Tags: xbox-network, games-for-windows-live

My Xbox 360 Gamertag, cptsupermrkt, is registered with/attached to the Windows Live account, myhotmailaccount@hotmail.com.

I bought Arkham City on the PC.  To even play the game, I must register my copy of the game with a "LIVE profile."  When I sign in with my *myhotmailaccount@hotmail.com*, but **before** I submit the product key, it tells me that it will only be registered to the LIVE account "cptsupermrkt", and is non-transferable.

Is this referring to my Xbox 360 Gamertag, or some kind of completely separate Games for Windows Live thing?  Are the Xbox 360 Gamertag and Games For Windows Live Gamertag the same thing?

If I submit, and register the game to "cptsupermrkt", then choose to transfer my Xbox 360 Gamertag to another Windows Live ID, will I still be able to play Arkham City, using the same Xbox 360 Gamertag cptsupermrkt, but attached to a different Windows Live ID?

Does "non-transferable" mean that the license can't be detached from the Windows Live ID, or the Gamertag (which CAN be transferred once every 30 days to another Windows Live ID)?

Answer (score 2):

Basically Xbox Live = Games for Windows Live.

It is the same service, using the same database, so you can use your gamertag and it'd be all good and golden. Key will be linked to gamertag forever.

Comment: [citation needed] ;)

Answer (score 1):

A gamertag and a Microsoft account (formerly called Windows Live ID) are linked, but can be separated. See [Change the Microsoft account associated with your gamertag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945419/en-au):

> **Important** Changing to a different Microsoft account will result in losing access to all Games for Windows LIVE licenses that were associated with the previous Microsoft account.

I *think* this means that your Games for Windows Live games will stay with your old Microsoft account.